# is SimpleDateFormat different in Java & Android?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I use below code in Java and works perfect!

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = format.parse("Sun, 11 May 2014 23:11:51 +0430");
```

but in Android I got exception !

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun, 11 May 2014 23:11:51 +0430" (at offset 0)
```

what's wrong ?!

Comment: default `Locale` maybe

Comment: could you explain more please ?!

Comment: Take a look at the [Android javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) There is a warning about locale. (To parse "Sun", the default locale is used and if it's for example french and not us/english, "Sun" is invalid, it's "Dim" in french)

Comment: @RC. you are my hero :X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the code will execute correctly if the default locale is english, otherwise will throw an exception. You can solve it adding the correct Locale.

```
//Locale locale = new Locale("en-US");  
Locale locale = Locale.US;  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", locale);
Date date = format.parse("Sun, 11 May 2014 23:11:51 +0430");
```

Probably the android device has a different language setting. Consider using a constant Locale as RC stated in the comment, in that case you wouldn't need the extra variable, use the constant directly in the constructor.

Comment: You really should use the [constants in `Locale`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#US)

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
Date date = format.parse("Sun, 11 May 2014 23:11:51 +0430");
```

If the Locale on your device is German for example your code executes if you parse this date:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.GERMAN);
Date date = format.parse("So, 11 Mai 2014 23:11:51 +0430");
```